# How to calculate mean squared error when a process is modeled with simple brownian motion?

Tags: mse, brownian-motion

I want to model a time series process with simple Brownian motion and want to know to what extent does the estimated model fit the original time series. While I am aware of the method two-sample Kolmigorov-Smirnov test, I also wish to compare the relative goodness of the simple Brownian vs. other types of model via AIC and/ or BIC. For which I would need to calculate mean squared error. However, I am not sure how and whether it is possible to calculate mean squared error in this context.

Comment: You have the predictions at all times $t$ and the observed values at all times $t$, right?

Comment: I only have the observed values. Am I correct that I can just get the prediction via Brownian motion with the estimated parameters? Then I think I got it. (But is it an acceptable practice?)